# How to Marshall any data type to string and Unmarshal from string to specific data type on condition

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling, unmarshalling

```
type State struct {
    Type      string    `json:"type" validate:"required"`
    Value     string    `json:"value"`
}
```

I have a struct like this. I need to pass the state to the API in different types.

eg : state can be either `{ type : 'boolean', value: true }` or `{ type : 'string', value: 'ABC' }`

And I'm storing it ( the **value** ) as a string in db.

Then when I'm passing from an API, I need to set the particular value considering the type (not as a string).

Same as this `{ type : 'boolean', value: true }`, `{ type : 'string', value: 'ABC' }`

How can I achieve this with Marshalling and Unmarshalling ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define marshal and unmarshal logic in your code.

```
type State struct {
    Type  string      `json:"type" validate:"required"`
    Value interface{} `json:"value"`
}

func (s *State) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    tmpMap := map[string]string{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(b, &tmpMap)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if tmpMap["type"] == "" {
        return errors.New("type not present")
    }
    if tmpMap["value"] == "" {
        return errors.New("value not present")
    }
    if tmpMap["type"] == "string" {
        s.Type = "string"
        s.Value = tmpMap["value"]
    } else if tmpMap["type"] == "boolean" {
        s.Type = "boolean"
        s.Value = tmpMap["value"] == "true"
    } else {
        //TODO implements other type
        return errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Unknown type %s", tmpMap["type"]))
    }
    return nil
}
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/BnD7HAuURzJ

Similarly, you can define `MarshalJSON` method on `State` struct to handle data serialization.

`func (c State) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)`

To store `State` db in single column in db you can implement

`func (c State) Value() (driver.Value, error)`

To build a state from DB columns you need to implement `Scan` method as

`func (e *State) Scan(value interface{}) error`

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If in marshalling and unmarshalling we're doing the type conversion, why do we need to implement custom `Value()`and `Scan()` as well ? Anyway thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: Since the driver/lib has no idea about the custom conversion, there's no automatic mechanism to convert string to some specific data type.

Comment: Got it. I'm bit cofused on this `UnmarshalJSON` . Here it's checking `s.Value = tmpMap["value"] == "true"` , it works when I pass this `{"type":"boolean", "value": "false"}`
. But what I want it to pass this **to** API `{"type":"boolean", "value": false}` and the same **from** API

Comment: No issue, in that case, you don't need the `UnmarshalJSON` method, it can automatically detect data type.